# DBAction together with IsAuthenticated:

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have the following code, but it complains:

could not find implicit value for parameter session: play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.Session

how could I fix it?

```
trait Secured extends Controller {

  /**
   * Retrieve the connected user id.
   */
  def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("email")

  /**
   * Redirect to login if the use in not authorized.
   */
  def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader): Result

  def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) =
    Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
      DBAction(request => f(user)(request))
    }
}
```

I have the following code:

```
object Application extends Controller with Secured { 
....
  def list(modelName: String, page: Int, orderBy: Int, filter: String) = IsAuthenticated{username=> implicit rs =>
    Ok(html.list(
      Model.byName(modelName),
      page,
      orderBy, filter
    ))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import slick's Session in your controller

```
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.Session
...
object Application extends Controller with Secured { 
...
```